# Read File strip whitespace

Tags: python

Working through CorePytho 
I can print a file using code below w/ eachLine,
If I remove the comma it is doublespaced.

I am trying to strip the whiteaspace w/o using the comma - no looking for an answer as much as why the code below only prints the last line of the .txt and not the preceding lines.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

'readTextFile.py == read and display a text file'

#get the filename
fname = raw_input('Enter the filename: ')
print

#attempt to open the file for reading
try:
    fobj = open(fname, 'r')
except IOError, e:
    print "*** file open error:", e
else:
    #display contents to the screen
    for eachLine in fobj:
        x = [fname.rstrip('\n') for eachLine in fobj]
        print eachLine,
    fobj.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over the file *inside your reading loop*. Python file objects have a 'read position'; each time you iterate over the file object that read position moves to the next line.

So inside the `for eachLine in fobj` loop, you are iterating over `fobj` *again* with the list comprehension.

In effect, you are reading just the first line, then storing the *rest* of the file (sans newline characters) in `x`. In Python 2, the `eachLine` variable you *reused* in the list comprehension loop is the same variable used in the outer `for` loop, so you end up with it still bound to the last line in your file. (In Python 3 list comprehensions got their own scope, so there the `eachLine` variable in the list comprehension is separate, like a local in another function).

If you wanted to strip the newline from the current line only, then do so:

```
eachLine = eachLine.rstrip('\n')
```

and leave the rest of the file to be processed in the subsequent iterations of your `for` loop.

Comment: it is printing the last line of text in the file. So it must be reading it? Or am I totally off.

Comment: @ScottParkis: ah, Python 2; the `eachLine` variable in the list comprehension leaks and is bound to the last line.

Comment: Thank you - the little I know about Python is everytime I get stuck the answer is simpler than I thought.